# place sprites in grid pattern within an area

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, grid

I have been trying to do this for a few hours in unity now but cant get my head around it. basically i have 4 points(vector3) 1 each for the 4 corners topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright. now i have a sprite that i use as a block what i want to do is basically fit X number of blocks within the four points. see the image below. Icant think of a way to do this right now.[image]
I would really appreciate any help in how to achieve this. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4):

first time here, have some time to kill so this is what I did. I'm assuming this is in a gui/2d game. This is what i did to get it to work.

create a canvas and add  4 UI images. These act as the 4 points(vector3's)
[image]
create a script and setup a way to draw lines so that you know that you are getting the right positions

```
using UnityEngine; 
using System.Collections; 

public class drawAndCalculate : MonoBehaviour { 
    public GameObject topLeft,topRight,bottomLeft,bottomRight,cube; 
    GameObject [] copyCube; 

    void OnDrawGizmos(){ 
        //fix the positions to make "perfect" straight tines 
        Vector3 topRight_pos = topRight.transform.position; 
        Vector3 botLeft_pos = bottomLeft.transform.position; 
        Vector3 botRight_pos = bottomRight.transform.position; 
        //adjuest them 
        topRight_pos.y = topLeft.transform.position.y; 
        botRight_pos.x = topRight_pos.x; 
        botLeft_pos.x = topLeft.transform.position.x; 
        botLeft_pos.y = botRight_pos.y; 

        //save them back 
        topRight.transform.position = topRight_pos; 
        bottomRight.transform.position = botRight_pos; 
        bottomLeft.transform.position = botLeft_pos; 

        Gizmos.color = Color.red; 
        Gizmos.DrawLine (topLeft.transform.position, topRight.transform.position); 
        Gizmos.color = Color.green; 
        Gizmos.DrawLine (topRight.transform.position, bottomRight.transform.position); 
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue; 
        Gizmos.DrawLine (bottomRight.transform.position, bottomLeft.transform.position); 
        Gizmos.color = Color.cyan; 
        Gizmos.DrawLine (bottomLeft.transform.position, topLeft.transform.position); 
    }
}
```

now you can move the images to make any rectangle. Now that you have the info is a matter of slicing into even proportions, so:

1. create an array of gameobjects,
2. get the width and height of the rectangle
3. resize each gameobject to the width/5 and height/5
4. position them in within the rectangle

--

```
// Use this for initialization 
void Start () { 

    //original is 100 by 100, Lets make o copy that is 50'50 
    //original question only want a SX S = 25 cubes 

    //get the size of the rectangle that the cubes wilt be placed 
    //using Local position since they are all inside canvas to get the actual values 
    float rectwidth =  topRight.transform.localPosition.x - topLeft.transform.localPosition.x; 
    float rectheight = topRight.transform.localPosition.y - bottomRight.transform. localPosition.y; 

    copyCube = new GameObject[25]; //make 25 
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    copyCube [i] = Instantiate (cube) as GameObject;//crate them 
    copyCube[i].transform.SetParent (this.transform.parent,false);//set the parent so that the scale is the some 
    copyCube[i].transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1 );//set scale just in case. size is based on scaLe of 2 
    copyCube[i].transform.GetComponent<RecTransform>().sizeDelta = new vector2(rectwidth/s,rectheight/5);//resizethen 


    //place them in the cube 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <5; j++) { 
            //figure out the location 
            float xpos = (rectwidth/5) * j; 
            float ypos = (rectheight/5) * i; 
            //remember to add the offset of where the cube starts 
            //in unity, origin(0,0) is on the bottom Left not top Left Like Java 
            //and add half of o cube because of the cube having the pivot in the middle 
            xpos..bottomLeft.transform.localPosition.x.(rectwidth/5)/2; 
            ypos += bottomLeft.transform.localPosition.y +(rectheight / 5) / 2; 
            copyCube [j+(i*5)].transform.localPosition = new Vector2 (xpos, ypos);//set the position 
            copyCube[j+(i*5)].name = "pepe"; 
        }
    }
}
```

done should be good to go!

[image]

Comment: In the future, please [upload images locally to stackexchange](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/where-should-i-upload-resources-linked-to-my-question-answer) & [post your code as code, not a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). I attempted to covert the code screenshot to text code, but you may need to review it for errors.